# Test membership and append in R?

Tags: r

I have two vectors, v1 and v2. I would like to find any of the strings in v2 that are also in v1 and then append the matches to a new vector. For example,

```
v1 <- c("foo", "bar", "baz")  
v2 <- c("zoo", "zap", "foo")  

# the code below is not remotely correct
# hopefully it demonstrates what I want to do:

matches <- c()

for(i in v2) {
   if(i %in% v1) {
       matches.append(i) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty much fine. You only need to fix the call to `append`:

```
matches <- c()

for(i in v2) {
    if(i %in% v1) {
        matches <- append(matches, i)
    }
}
```

Something like this is better, though:

```
matches <- v2[v2 %in% v1]
```

Answer (score 1):

the following maybe be what you want

```
matches<-v1[v1%in%v2]
```